# SPARQL how to receive not empty ?s in: select ?s ?p ?o WHERE {<http://subject.url> ?p ?o}

Tags: sparql

So, when I specify let's say the value of the subject in WHERE clause, I will not get it back as a result. But I need it, how to do that?

For example, when I have a query:

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE{
  <http://subject.url/title> ?p ?o .
 }
```

As a result I will have only columns of ?p and ?o, but empty ?s. What if I want the whole triple back, with http://subject.url/title in the ?s column?

Comment: `SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE{
  ?s ?p ?o .FILTER(?s = <http://subject.url/title>)
 }`

Comment: Even better `select ?s ?p ?o  { values ?s { <http://...> } ?s ?p ?o }`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE {
  BIND (<http://subject.url/title> as ?s)
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bind

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to use [**values**](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data). **Values** lets you specify one (or more) variables and any number of values that those variables should be bound to.  While you can use **bind** to handle the simple case of just one value, **values** (in my opinion) is nicer because: (i) it's less typing; and (ii) it's more easily extensible, if you want a few values of **?s** later on.

```sql
select ?s ?p ?o {
  values ?s { <http://subject.url/title> }
  ?s ?p ?o
}
```

If, later on, you want information about two values of **?s**, you can do that easily:

```sql
select ?s ?p ?o {
  values ?s { <http://subject.url/title1>
              <http://subject.url/title2> }
  ?s ?p ?o
}
```